# Is the big o for the following O(n^2*log(n)) or O(n^3*log(n))

Tags: big-o

Is the big o for the following O(n^2*log(n)) or O(n^3*log(n))?

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
 for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
  for(int k=0;k<n;k*=2){
      System.out.print("test");
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: What do you think? Draw a table and see when will the last iteration happen.

Comment: It never terminates (for n > 0). Do you really mean `int k = 0` in that last loop?

Comment: Please edit your question or you can't get a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
O(n^2*log(n))
```

First two loops are proportional to n, last one is log n.

Of course, it's also O(n^3*log(n)) since big-O just specifies an upper bound, and if O(n^2*log(n)) is an upper bound, so is O(n^3*log(n))

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is **O(n<sup>2</sup> log<sub>2</sub> n)** or generally we can say **O(n<sup>2</sup> log n)** .